# DO YOU KNOW OF ANY OOP dynamic language that has field instantiation level?

Tags: oop, prototype, prototype-programming

Trying to orthogonalize the prototype and class concepts for an interpreted dynamic language, I arrived to the conclusion that classes in their more generic form in order to be able to define not only objects but classes too, SHOULD BY ABLE to hold not only fields for their direct instances, but also fields for instances of their instances and so on. 
So every field of a class ( or meta class if you like ) could have a level that indicates after how many instantiations the field will appear as a storage location where to store data.

My question isn't if that is right or not ( but feel free to clarify if curious ) 
but if you know about any language that already allows that capability, or at least any article that speaks about that possibility.
As my experience with OOP ( object oriented programming ) is limited, I would like to have some indications on where to find some advanced concepts like the one mentioned before.

Just to clarify: A meta-class of that kind could define as it's instances classes that have a static variable A and two fields X Y. 
A C++ like tentative syntax could be:

```
metaclass mc1 { 
  var A;
  meta var X,Y;
} c1,c2;
```

with the above definition we would had created two classes c1 and c2 that normally would be defined as:

```
class c1{
  static var A;
  var X,Y;
}

class c2{
 static var A;
 var X,Y;
}
```

When we create an instance of c1 it isn't the same thing as creating an instance of c2 because the static var A is different between c1 and c2;
So in that case in the metaClass mc1 we have the definition of a 
normal field A ( normal level 1 ), and the definition of two fields X,Y of level 2 .
The fields of level 2 will appear as storage space when we create an instance of an instance of mc1.
Morover classes c1 and c2 may be get more different by the later (dynamic) addition of more static variables or field variables ( prototype field addition ).

Comment: And how would you handle a linked list, or any other self-referential structure?

Comment: I didn't understood the exact meaning of what you say, could you precise please ?

Comment: Gee, lay off with the caps.

Comment: Your description isn't quite clear (quite confusing even); your phrase "instances of their instances" in particular doesn't make sense. My first guess was that you were talking about inlining the ivars of objects held in ivars, but it sounds like that's not right. Could you perhaps give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I *think* C++ generic classes do that, you could check with a quick test program.

Comment: Please look at the code, and it could be more clear what I mean by instance of instance. Believe me that my mind was confused during the last 15 days, and is clearing slowly up.

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out template classes that may do the work. Sure the work is done "externally" to the language as anyway should be because "class" do live only in code and not in memory.

Comment: What I am looking for is for an interpreted language having classes as "living objects" and that allows for that kind of "meta", just if you know of ?